# How to set Color of control without using the Enumeration?

Tags: c#

I want to set the color of my control using a string variable with a value of say "Blue".
Normally you would set it:

Label1.Color = Color.Blue;

But now I want to replace Color.Blue with the value that is in my string variable, like:

Label1.Color = sColor; // sColor = "Blue"

But I get the error: Cannot convert type 'string' to "System.Drawing.Color"

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Color.FromName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname.aspx) function to pass in a string:

```
Color slateBlue = Color.FromName("SlateBlue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could parse the enumeration, or alternatively map the values to the enumeration using a case statement.

The enum parsing is done as follows:

```
System.Drawing.Color colorValue = (System.Drawing.Color)Enum.Parse(typeof(System.Drawing.Color), sColor);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response:

I get this error:

Type provided must be an Enum.
Parameter name: enumType